# TypeError : tan^-1 (tan inverse) of the ratio of two dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have two dataframe columns "vibration_X" and "vibration_Y".Also I have few zero values in some columns. I want to create new column "theta" which would be the ratio of tan inverse of vibration_Y and vibration_X.

Below is my sample data:

```
     vibration_Y  vibration_X
0           10            7
1           10            8
2            9            8
3           10           11
4           13            5
5            3            0
6           12            8
7           12            9
8           11           10
9           10           11
```

Below is my code that I have tried and for which I am getting error:

```
df['theta'] = math.atan(df['vibration_Y']/df['vibration_X'].astype(float))
```

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'

Comment: Functions in `math` only work on scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`numpy.arctan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html):

```
df['theta'] = np.arctan(df['vibration_Y']/df['vibration_X'])
print (df)
   vibration_Y  vibration_X     theta
0           10            7  0.960070
1           10            8  0.896055
2            9            8  0.844154
3           10           11  0.737815
4           13            5  1.203622
5            3            0  1.570796
6           12            8  0.982794
7           12            9  0.927295
8           11           10  0.832981
9           10           11  0.737815
```

Comment: @Jezreal , exactly! I didn't know that there is a arctan inbuilt function in numpy. Anyways ,thanks a lot for the input.

Comment: Especially since `vibration_X` can be 0, a better choice here is `numpy.arctan2`.